# PHP Multidimensional Array -- Resorting array

Tags: php, post, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```
teamMembers[teamMembers][0][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][0][Email];
teamMembers[teamMembers][1][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][1][Email];
```

etc.

The problem is that sometimes the data is like this:

```
teamMembers[teamMembers][0][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][0][Email];
teamMembers[teamMembers][3][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][3][Email];
teamMembers[teamMembers][4][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][4][Email];
teamMembers[teamMembers][7][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][7][Email];
```

Is there any way I can resort a randomised array so the above array would look like this...

```
teamMembers[teamMembers][0][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][0][Email];
teamMembers[teamMembers][1][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][1][Email];
teamMembers[teamMembers][2][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][2][Email];
teamMembers[teamMembers][3][Name];
teamMembers[teamMembers][3][Email];
```

I'm guessing not, but it sure would help me if it was possible! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$teamMembers['teamMembers'] = array_values($teamMembers['teamMembers']);
```

Comment: Huzzah! Well I can't believe it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ksort($teamMembers['teamMembers']);
```